# Value of X reset upon increase

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have a discord bot I am making in which I am trying to make a counter which increments upon a command being ran. *(The command is named "click")* I have tried to log variables in console at multiple points and upon increase of the variable it resets to 0 for a unknown *(to me)* reason. The code of the function responsible for incrementing the clicks is:

```
public int clicks;
int x = 1;
string item = "default value";
[Command("click")]
public async Task ClickAsync()
{
    clicks++;
    await ReplyAsync($"You have found a {x}{item}! You now have {clicks} coins!");
    Console.WriteLine(clicks.ToString());
}
```

the full code; as the previous section was likely not the problem, although still a possibility, is:

```
public int clicks;
int x = 1;
string item = "default value";
[Command("click")]
public async Task ClickAsync()
{
    clicks++;
    await ReplyAsync($"You have found a {x}{item}! You now have {clicks} coins!");
    Console.WriteLine(clicks.ToString());
}

int de;
string name;
String[] items = { "a", "b" };
[Command("shop")]
public async Task ShopAsync(string item)
{
    foreach (string i in items)
    {
        if (i == item)
        {
            name = i;
            de = getPrice(i);
            if (clicks >= de)
            {

                await ReplyAsync($"You have purchased a {name} for {de}");
                clicks -= de;
            }
            else
            {
                await ReplyAsync($"You have {clicks} coins. You need more.");
            }
        }

    }

}
[Command("help")]
public async Task TaskAsync()
{
    await ReplyAsync("Help Module: {}");
}
public int getPrice(string de)
{
    return 1;
}
```

If needed, the console output is:

```
15:45:48 Gateway     Ready
1
1
1    #| The amount of 1's is equal to the amount of times the "click" command was ran.
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Command modules in Discord.Net are transient, which means it's created when the command is executed and destroyed once completed. As such you field variables will not persist between command executions. You'd need to store any data that needs to persist in another class and have the command access that. So basically create a service class to maintain state for any data that is meant to persist.

Comment: Can you add your main method to your question showing how you are creating the `CommandService` and adding modules to it? Maybe we can help you add a service class. Please remember to remove your bot's authentication token before posting if it is visible in the main method.